# How to decide the arrangement of an individual telescope in an astronomical interferometer?

Tags: astrophysics, instrument

Let's take the example of GMRT radio telescope, where individual telescopes are arranged in Y pattern. Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the telescopes form *baselines* which can be plotted out in the uv-plane. The performance of an interferometer depends on the largest baseline, shortest baseline as well as the fill factor of the uv-plane during the measurement. [image]

Look at the image above. The dots in the right image represents the baselines between each and everyone of the different telescopes as well as the conjugate of each baseline. If we look at the left image there is a baseline between the leftmost telescope and its neighbour, as well as with the telescope and the 2nd closest telescope and so forth.

The shortest baseline determines the largest object that can be resolved with the interferometer. The longest baseline determines the smallest features distinguishable by the interferometer and the % of the uv-plane that's filled increase sensitivity.

Some interferometers who take measurements during prolonged time accounts for the earths rotations as well, thus filling a larger portion of the uv-plane.

This is why the different interferometers are configured the way they are. VLA in America for example rotates their interferometer between a number of different configurations during the year to change sensitivity/resolution etc during the year to fit different experiments/measurements.

I hope this ansered your question.